# Callback function in c# - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have class A which define class B:

```
B b=new B()
```

I would like to call to a function in class A from B.when I tried to make this function- static- i got an error cause i have in that function-

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke...
```

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just pass a reference of A to B.

Something like

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        B b = new B(this);   
    }
}

public class B
{
    public B(A a)
    {

    }
}
```

Or you could make it a property of B.

Something like

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        B b = new B
                  {
                      MyA = this
                  };
    }
}

public class B
{
    public A MyA;
}
```